# Array as a C++ class member variable

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

Can I use array as a member variable of a class in c++ in the following way? or Should I declare it as a pointer? The following code works fine. Is it correct way of doing it? (I made it public just for simplicity). I'm also not sure whether I'm using the map correctly or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class SimpleMap{
public:
    map<string,int> m;
    int i;
    int j[];
    SimpleMap(int ii);
};

SimpleMap::SimpleMap(int ii){
    i = ii;
}



int main(){
    SimpleMap mm(5);
    mm.m["one"] = 1;

    cout<<"hi hru";

    cout<<mm.m["one"];

    mm.j[0] = 11;
    cout << mm.j[0];
}
```

EDIT: I've add map member variable.

Comment: Are you sure that works? It shouldn't.

Comment: There's a difference between "appearing to work" and "working". Just because nothing is obviously crashing or something doesn't mean that this is doing something reasonable.

Comment: The header `string.h` is deprecated. Use `cstring` if you really need the C string manipulation API. But you should prefer `string` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you already have a pointer. But it's uninitialized.

Setting `j[0]` will work in some cases, sure, but you're writing to unallocated memory, or worse, memory used by another object. Basically you're creating a massive hole in your application.

Consider using a `std::vector`, which simply does all the allocating/deallocating for you. If that's not an option, at least initialize the array and don't go further than you allocated.

`j[]` is simply `*j` which is only a pointer to a random memory address. Very, very, very bad.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether I'm using the map properly?

Comment: You are. It's **very** hard to create memory leaks with a `std` object. :-)

Comment: @Tom: `; new std::vector<double>(500);`. That was easy! >_> ... <_< ... >_>

Comment: @Xeo Well, who would use a vector like that anyway? Besides, a good compiler will give a warning about that.

Comment: @Tom: It was just meant as a joke answer to your "**very** hard". :)

Comment: @Xeo: Oh :-) Humor is **very** hard in these comment boxes (see what I did there?).

Answer (score 3):

```
int j[];
```

Is not what you think it is. This actually defines a pointer: `int* j;`, which is left uninitialized, and from which you're reading in the uninitialized state, which is undefined behaviour, aka *wrong*.

Just use a `std::vector`.

Comment: I'm actually confused how to use these compound data structures as data members of a class. I posted another snippet which uses map as data member. Could plz see if I am doing it wrong and that piece is also working fine.

Comment: Why does such a declaration as a class member compile fine, but it's an error if you put it in function body (of both free and member function)?

Comment: @Jrok: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Lamia: The map is fine as you use it, though you won't get away with only using [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) later on. :) Get friendly with [`map.find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Comment: @Xeo What if the author had written `int j[3];`, would `j` still be a pointer?

Comment: This is not correct. This is (if supported) a variable array member, not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

No,I think `int j[];` is used when you initialize the array on it's declaration.You should provide an upper bound to the array.I think this would be correct `int j[]={3,2,1};` .

Comment: Too bad you can't do that inside of a class definition.

Comment: @Tom: Not if you have a `int j[]` member, and especially not with that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As I found that on google I wanted to clear up a confusion here in the answers: Using `T name[]` as the last member of a struct is called a "flexible array member" and defined as an extension to C by e.g. GCC and Clang. Example use:

```
struct Array{
  int len;
  float ar[];
};
// Create
Array* foo = malloc(sizeof(Array) + 100 * sizeof(float));
foo.len = 100;
// Use
for(int i=0; i<foo.len; i++) foo.ar[i] = i * M_PI;
```

The special member is not actually a member but some compiler magic and similar to `struct Array{ int len;  float ar[100]; };` but you can choose the size at runtime.

However in C++ this is much harder to use as you need to take object lifetime into consideration. So **do NOT use this as-is in C++**.

In the case of the OP: You probably wanted a real pointer there and need an allocation for the array pointed to. Obviously a `std::vector` solves most of the trouble as already pointed out.