# C++ My string array variable has errors even though it shouldn't

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here is the code in question. I'm trying to get the number of attacks the Char has and with the string array I will name the attacks but it gives me the errors you will see below.

```
#include <iostream>

class Chars
{
public:
    int Attacks;
    int Stm;
    std::string name;
    int Hp;
    std::string AtkNames[Attacks];

};

int main()
{
    Chars Stats;
    Stats.Attacks = 5;
    Stats.Stm = 1050;
    Stats.name = "Barber";
    Stats.Hp = 73000;
    Stats.AtkNames = { "atk1", "atk2", "atk3", "atk4", "atk5" };

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
1>C:\Users\Calvyn\source\repos\DataManagement\DataManagement\ok.cpp(10,33): error C2327: 'Chars::Attacks': is not a type name, static, or enumerator
1>C:\Users\Calvyn\source\repos\DataManagement\DataManagement\ok.cpp(10,26): error C2065: 'Attacks': undeclared identifier
1>C:\Users\Calvyn\source\repos\DataManagement\DataManagement\ok.cpp(21,20): error C3863: array type 'std::string [1]' is not assignable
```

Comment: `AtkNames[Attacks];` is not valid C++ - size must be a compile-time constant. Use `std::vector<std::string>` and remove `Attacks` as it becomes superfluous.

Comment: if this is really about a haircutter rather than a barbarian, its gona be an innovative game

Comment: *"even though it shouldn't"* -- well, yeah, on one level everyone *should* write code that has no errors. On another level, though, the code you wrote does have errors, so the compiler *should* report those errors.

Comment: Also, `<iostream>` is not required to `#include <string>`  (or to otherwise declare string types, such as `std::string`).     With some compilers/libraries, `<iostream>` does provide access to `std::string`, but not all do.    If you want your code to work portably, you need to `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string AtkNames[Attacks];
```

is problematic. You cannot have an array member with a size that is not known a compile time. Your object must have a known fixed size.

`int Attacks;` would need to be a `constexpr`, or static const.

Even if it were, you cannot do:

```
Stats.AtkNames = { "atk1", "atk2", "atk3", "atk4", "atk5" };
```

You cannot assign whole arrays in C++.

Comment: Alternatives: [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), a much, much smarter fixed size array, and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), an array with dynamic size.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the definition

```
std::string AtkNames[Attacks];
```

**Attacks** (I guess your intention was to have some const or global for the size of this array) is not defined before this line.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [Array as a C++ class member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690373/array-as-a-c-class-member-variable)

You either need to use an array defined at runtime

```
std::string AtkNames[5]; // size 5, or whatever you want
```

Or you can use a vector and it'll work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Chars
{
public:
    int Attacks;
    int Stm;
    std::string name;
    int Hp;
    std::vector<std::string> AtkNames;

};

int main()
{
    Chars Stats;
    Stats.Attacks = 5;
    Stats.Stm = 1050;
    Stats.name = "Barber";
    Stats.Hp = 73000;
    //Stats.AtkNames = { "atk1", "atk2", "atk3", "atk4", "atk5" };
    Stats.AtkNames.push_back("atk1");
    Stats.AtkNames.push_back("atk2");
    return 0;
}
```